# invalid object or resource mysqli_stmt errors

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Am trying to get every machines ip address and insert into a database on my website but for some reason am getting the following errors:

```
Warning: mysqli_stmt_bind_param(): invalid object or resource mysqli_stmt...

Warning: mysqli_stmt_execute(): invalid object or resource mysqli_stmt...

Warning: mysqli_stmt_store_result(): invalid object or resource mysqli_stmt...

Warning: mysqli_stmt_num_rows(): invalid object or resource mysqli_stmt...

Warning: mysqli_stmt_execute(): invalid object or resource mysqli_stmt in..
```

Warning: mysqli_stmt_execute(): invalid object or resource mysqli_stmt in...

And this is my code:

```
<?php
$deviceip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
//check if ip is already in database
if(isset($deviceip)){
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE deviceip=?";
    $resstmt = mysqli_stmt_init($db);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($resstmt,"s",$deviceip);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($resstmt);
    //did we get a match?
    mysqli_stmt_store_result($resstmt);
    $resultCheck = mysqli_stmt_num_rows($resstmt);
    if($resultCheck ==0){
        $sql = "INSERT INTO deviceips(deviceip) VALUES (?)";
        $resstmt = mysqli_stmt_init($db);
        mysqli_stmt_prepare($resstmt,$sql);
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($resstmt,"s",$deviceip);;
        mysqli_stmt_execute($resstmt);
    }
}?>
```

Comment: You muss the `mysqli_stmt_prepare`. see https://www.w3schools.com/Php/func_mysqli_stmt_init.asp

Comment: w3schools method works.Thanks@Jens

Answer (score 0):

As you are getting so many errors, I'd suppose there is no connection to the database. If you have posted all your code, then you maybe missed to establish a connection.
Try these lines before your queries:

`$db = mysqli_connect(SERVER_DNS_OR_IP, DATABASE_USER, USER_PASSWORD, DATABASE_NAME);
if(mysqli_connect_errno())
{ 
  ... do some error handling...
}`

Replace the capitalized data with your own database data.

Comment: the connection is fine it was an issue with having multiple prepared statements.